# Meaning of micro-sd card symbols

Tags: sd, symbol

I hope this is the right stackexchange site to ask this question. I'd like to now the meaning of these symbols, visible in the front of two different micro sd cards of the same model:

[image: symbol1]
[image: symbol2]

Backgroung (in case anyone wants to know): I have three sd cards, whose model is Kingston SDC10G2/16GB. Two of them work for my particular purpose (using a raspberry pi), the other one doesn't. I've realized that the cards that work and the one that doesn't don't look the same (I was trying to post pictures of them, but I can't attach more than two images until I have a reputation of 10). The first symbol is on the card that doesn't work, the other symbol is on the ones that do.

In a computer, all three cards perform flawlessly. A badblock analysis reveals none of them has bad blocks. I'm asking about those symbols thinking that maybe the have something to do with my problem.

Comment: They should all work, did you check the file system format on them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_Declaration_of_Conformity

Comment: @Captainj2001 yes, I tried every conceivable test. And I didn't try the "faulty" card with the raspberry just once, I tried at least 7 times. I format the card in the pc and flash a new os: everything is fine. I put the sd card in the raspberry and use it (running programs, browsing the internet, anything like that): everything is fine. I do an apt-get update: everything gets corrupted.

Comment: Do you really think the manufacturer knows which card is faulty in advance (so they label it differently), but sells it anyway?

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's it. So, it appears that the o in the first image and the v in the second one are not related to the "FCC Declaration of Conformity" symbol...

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev no, of course not. But I do think that the cards may have different characteristics, and that those of the "non working card" may not be supported by my raspberry. The card is not faulty. I can put it in a computer (and do a badblocks test) or in a digital camera and no problem occurs. And that's the market that sd cards manufacturers aim to. In a raspberry a lot of small write access to the card may need to be made, and that's different from just writing a big chuck of data (like a photograph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FCC label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_Declaration_of_Conformity) denotes that the device conforms to FCC standards, meaning that it has limited electromagnetic interference with other devices.

That has little to do with bad blocks though.

Comment: Thank you @Bort. So, the fact that one symbol has an o next to it, and the other one has a v, has no meaning? And I don't think the card has bad blocks (at least that's what a badblocks linux test says). I was asking if it indicates something about the way to use the sd card.

Comment: Oops I read "Some of them have bad blocks"! I am not able to find any documentation on the meaning of "V", "O", or "0". I thought it may be FCC related, but it's hard to search for single letters.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. This doesn't fully answer the question, but it doesn't seem like I'm going to get a more complete one, so I'm marking it as accepted.